# I'd like to run this simple re-ordering code in a GPU with an OpenCl-kernel. Is it possible?

Tags: doparallel

I'd like to run this simple C code in GPU in an OpenCl-Kernel. Is it possible?

```
#include <stdio.h>        
int main()
{
  int a[15]={7,8,0,4,13,1,14,5,10,2,3,11,12,6,9};
  int b[15];
  printf(input datas:  ");
  for (i=0;i<15;i++) printf("%3d",a[i]);
  printf("\n");
  for (i=0;i<15;i++) b[a[i]]=i;
  for (i=0;i<15;i++) printf("%3d",b[i]);
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

My input and output data should be:

```
Input:  7 8 0 4 13 1 14 5 10 2 3 11 12 6 9
Output: 2 5 9 10 3 7 13 0 1 14 8 11 12 4 6
```

Comment: // input datas :  7  8  0  4 13  1 14  5 10  2  3 11 12  6  9
// output datas:  2  5  9 10  3  7 13  0  1 14  8 11 12  4  6

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although it will be really inefficient because of those random memory accesses. Simplifying it a lot, GPUs work better when work-items (instances of an OpenCL kernel) access memory sequentially.

Having said this, to do this in C and OpenCL you need to perform the following steps (again I'm simplifying a bit):

- Include OpenCL headers.
- Write the OpenCL kernel itself, and either put it in a string in your `main()` save it to a `.cl` file and read it into a string from your `main()`.
- Get desired GPU device and create a context.
- Create an OpenCL command queue.
- Create the `input` and `output` device buffers.
- Write the desired information to the `input` device buffer (via the command queue).
- Create an OpenCL program (from the kernel source string), build it, get the kernel object and set its parameters.
- Run the kernel (via the command queue), which will perform the desired operation, reading from the `input` buffer and writing to the `output` buffer.
- Read back the data from the `output` device buffer (via the command queue) and show it on screen.
- Release all the created OpenCL objects.

See this [link](https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-opencl-and-gpu-computing/) on how to get started with OpenCL and GPU computing. It gives a good ideia of how something like this is done. You will notice that doing this in pure C is very verbose, so either use a wrapper library such as [cf4ocl](http://fakenmc.github.io/cf4ocl/), use [C++](https://github.khronos.org/OpenCL-CLHPP/), or use some other language with higher-level bindings (e.g. [Python](https://documen.tician.de/pyopencl/)).